# MailService IO failed (java.io.IOException: Internal error)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am getting the below error when sending emails in GAE. This stopped working all of a sudden. Can someone help me understand where the problem might be or any debugging ideas would be appreicated. As you can see from the attached image I am well withing my quota.

**MailService IO failed (java.io.IOException: Internal error)**

```
public boolean email(final Player to, List<Player> players)
    {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        try
        {
            Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("validemail@gmail.com"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to.getEmail()));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("arav@yahoo.com"));
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, new InternetAddress("validemail@gmail.com"));

            msg.setSubject("Registration confirmation.");

            msg.setText("tx for registering");
            logger.info("sending email to " + to.getEmail());
            logger.info(msgBody.toString());
            Transport.send(msg);
            logger.info("sent email to " + to.getEmail());
        }
        catch (AddressException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        catch (MessagingException e)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check the dashboard logs? Anything there?

Comment: nothing special on the dashboard page or in admin logs

Comment: Just thinking out loud: did you perhaps remove the validemail@gmail.com account from the application administrator list?

Comment: can you let me know where to loot for this configuration so that I can check it. This was working initially and I have not touched any config since i started experimenting with GAE.

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview.html#Sending_Mail

Comment: validemail@gmail.com is infact the owner of this project. So i am not sure why it is not working...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered exactly the same problem tonight. After some investigation, I found this GAE issue: http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5776, which indicated that the GAE instance ID should not be the same as the sender email ID. For example, in "abcd.appspot.com", when the sender ID is "abcd@xxxx.com", it would fail to send email.

I haven't tried it yet, but I'm sure I used same IDs in my error case. I will test it tomorrow and update this post about wether it works or not.

Thanks,
J

---

Update [Dec 15, 2011 GMT+8]:

I tried it but still has problems, so I posted comments to the following GAE issues:

http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5776
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5320

Comment: Just saw a post mentioning "such issues due to billing not being turned on".

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/tSl6D_cgrbs

Comment: I checked the function again, it worked today. Stange, I didn't do anything with it.